# Single selection listbox selected items to another listbox

Tags: wpf, list, listbox, selection, selecteditem

I've tried quite a few options but none of them has gotten me closer to the results.

I'm really new to WPF, so I'm sorry form my perhaps trivial question.
I have a single selection `listbox` and I need to add the `selected` item to another listbox. I tried to create a list add the selected item on `mouse click` to this list and then bind the other listbox to it. I tried just declaring that

```
chosen_list.SelectedValue=selection_list.SelectedItem;
```

I tried to create an observable collection, but nothing works.
All I get in the second listbox is the first chosen value.

Is there a way to do it without the observable collection?

Please help and Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mustafa sais (he could have elaborated a bit), this is an action that needs to be implemented every time a new selection is made in the first list.  So I would hook up the "SelectionChanged" event of your first list.  In this event handler, you can then Clear the content of the second list and add the newly selected item to that second list.

Here is a VERY simple example of what I mean:

Here is the XAML page:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="lstFirstList" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBoxItem Content="This is a test 1" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="This is a test 2" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="This is a test 3" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="This is a test 4" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="This is a test 5" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="This is a test 6" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="This is a test 7" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="This is a test 8" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="This is a test 9" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="This is a test 10" />
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox x:Name="lstSecondList" Grid.Column="1">

    </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the Code Behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lstSecondList.Items.Clear();
        if (e.AddedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            ListBoxItem vSelectedItem = (ListBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0];
            ListBoxItem vNewItem = new ListBoxItem();
            vNewItem.Content = vSelectedItem.Content;
            lstSecondList.Items.Add(vNewItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Now there might be a better way to do this, but at the very least that should get you started!

Comment: I would be interested if anyone knows how to do this via pure binding....  My "sub-brain" says it should be possible!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use event SelectionChanged http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx